# Matplotlib surface plot showing same color for different values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, surface, colormap

Why do all points get the same value? I would like color to vary with energy.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from numpy import *

x = linspace(0.2, 2, 11)
y = linspace(0.1, 1, 11)
alpha, beta = meshgrid(x,y)
energy = matrix(loadtxt('energyPlotfileN6.txt'))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(alpha, beta, energy, cmap='summer', vmin=energy.min(), vmax=energy.max())
plt.xlabel("alpha")
plt.ylabel("beta")
ax.set_zlabel("energy")
plt.show()
```

The result is shown below

[Surface plot without desired colour mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmrso.png)

Comment: Do you get the same output if you replace `cmap='summer'` with `cmap=cm.summer`?

Comment: Yes I do. @jonchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used the answer from above (add the `cstride` and `rstride` arguments), but wanted to add a visualization of the difference...

In my case I'm plotting terrain...

No stride:

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(topo['lon'], topo['lat'], topo['value'],
                       cmap='terrain', vmax=2800, vmin=1300,
                       linewidth=.1, antialiased=False)
```

[image]

With stride:

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(topo['lon'], topo['lat'], topo['value'],
                           cmap='terrain', vmax=2800, vmin=1300,
                           linewidth=.1, antialiased=False,
                           rstride=1, cstride=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
ax.plot_surface(alpha, beta, energy, cstride=1, rstride=1, cmap='summer', vmin=energy.min(), vmax=energy.max())
```

Note the `cstride` and `rstride` parameters.

[Axes3D.plot_surface documentation](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_surface).

Comment: Amen to using the cstride and rstride parameters!